# Error in cor(exprs(gse), use = "c") : no complete element pairs

Tags: r, rna-seq

I'm trying to plot a heat map for a "GSE133399", I retrieved the GSE using GEOquery package and then assigned to an object and then tried to plot a heatmap, but I was not successful, I used the following code in RStudio:

```
install.packages("BiocManager")
BiocManager::install("GEOquery")
library(GEOquery)
## change my_id to be the dataset that you want.
my_id <- "GSE133399"
gse <- getGEO(my_id)
length(gse)
gse <- gse[[1]]
gse
pData(gse) ## print the sample information
fData(gse) ## print the gene annotation
exprs(gse) ## print the expression data

## exprs get the expression levels as a data frame and get the distribution
summary(exprs(gse))
exprs(gse) <- log2(exprs(gse))
boxplot(exprs(gse),outline=FALSE)
library(dplyr)
sampleInfo <- pData(gse)
sampleInfo
## source_name_ch1 and characteristics_ch1.1 seem to contain factors we might need for the analysis. Let's pick just those columns

sampleInfo <- select(sampleInfo, source_name_ch1,characteristics_ch1.1)

## Optionally, rename to more convenient column names
sampleInfo <- rename(sampleInfo,group = source_name_ch1, patient=characteristics_ch1.1)
sampleInfo
install.packages("pheatmap")
library(pheatmap)
## argument use="c" stops an error if there are any missing data points

corMatrix <- cor(exprs(gse),use="c")
```

I get this error:

```
Error in cor(exprs(gse), use = "c") : no complete element pairs
```

I also  tried this:

```
corMatrix <- cor(exprs(gse),use="c", use="complete.obs")
```

I get this error:

```
Error in cor(exprs(gse), use = "c", use = "complete.obs") : 
  formal argument "use" matched by multiple actual arguments
```

I want to achieve this plot:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The GSE133399 dataset contains both ATAC-seq and RNA-seq data, none of which can be queried with GEOquery which works only for microarray data.

`exprs(gse) ## print the expression data` returns an empty object as you might have noticed, therefore the errors in the lines that follow this command.

On the bottom of https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/geo/query/acc.cgi?acc=GSE133399 at the `Supplementary file` section you can download FPKM-transformed count data and use these. I would be careful though as FPKM is not ideal for inter-sample comparison. I personally always (if feasable) download the raw data and then process myself, but for a guess on what is going on the FPKMs probably will do.

Comment: How do you process the data of GSE in this case? I looked for questions that have the same kind of data, but I couldn’t find any, what do you recommend @ATpoint ?

Comment: You cannot use GSE data here. It is for microarray as I said above. Download raw data (fastq, this is NGS not array), and then align them. If you are new to this then simply use the FPKM that are provided.

Comment: I want to do both from raw data and FPKM @ATpoint, how and where to get the raw fastq data?

Comment: On the bottom of the GEO page, you see the "Relations" category, which points to NCBI BioProject [PRJNA551397](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/bioproject/PRJNA551397). There, under "project data", you see "SRA experiments". Click on the number [28](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/sra?linkname=bioproject_sra_all&from_uid=551397), which takes you to the sequence read archive page for the samples. Now click on [Send to run selector](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/Traces/study/?WebEnv=MCID_5f8c99363a76fa4c437fb1d5&query_key=2&GALAXY_URL=https%3A%2F%2Fusegalaxy.org%2Ftool_runner%3Ftool_id%3Dsra_source)

Comment: The recommended way to download these runs from the SRA is to use the SRA toolkit, specifically the program `fasterq-dump` from it. See [here](https://github.com/ncbi/sra-tools/wiki/HowTo:-fasterq-dump) for the How-to. Basically, just run `fasterq-dump <RUN ACCESSION>`. E.g.: `fasterq-dump SRR9606476` for the first run of you experiment. Download the SRA toolkit [here](https://github.com/ncbi/sra-tools/wiki/01.-Downloading-SRA-Toolkit)

Comment: @user432797 You typically download the fastq files either from NCBI or ENA. Check sra-explorer.info which can search and provide download links for datasets. I also wrote a (today a bit deprecated given sra-explorer exists) tutorial that might be interesting, see https://www.biostars.org/p/325010/ It is not recommended imho to directly download files via fasterq-dump, that is often unstable in my experience. The tutorial covers recommended approaches, or simply use the download links from-sra.explorer.info to get fastq right away (my preferred approach).